# Weird comparison in third-party javascript library

Tags: javascript, unicode

While I was fixing some js syntax to avoid problems with minification I spotted this block in a third-party js library:

```
if ('\u0041' == 'A') {
   var u = n.userAgent;
   if (u.indexOf('Safari') == -1) { 
     [...] 
   }
}
```

The block has no else condition following, and basically checks for browser type and version... anyway I don't see why it should compare between the unicode code for the 'A' character and, well, the 'A' character! :/

Has anybody encountered a condition like this before? Am I missing something or it's useless?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be a pretty old library which **test javaScript's support for Unicode**.

For an old Browser like  Netscape Navigator 4, it only supports `Latin-1` encoding `'\xXX'` other than full Unicode support `'\uXXXX'`

Comment: Would have to be even older than Netscape 4, I think! Certainly there's no reason to be checking for it today.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's used to detect if the browser is safari 2.0.4, because it has problems understanding regular expressions:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/689517?start=0&tstart=0